# Cannot make Cuda program

Tags: c++, c, cuda, makefile

I have got in the same directory 3 files:

*hellomake.cu*

```
#include<hellofunc.h>
 int main(){
 myPrintHelloMake();
 return 0;
}
```

*hellofunc.c*

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void myPrintHelloMake(void){
 printf("Hello dummy!\n");
 return;
}
```

*hellofunc.h*

```
void myPrintHelloMake(void)
```

*Makefile*

```
CC=/usr/local/cuda-5.5/bin/nvcc
CFLAGS=-I.

hellomake: hellomake.cu hellofunc.c
         $(CC) -o hellomake hellomake.cu hellofunc.c -I.
```

But when I run through terminal make it prints out:

---

/usr/local/cuda-5.5/bin/nvcc -o hellomake hellomake.cu hellofunc.c -I.
/tmp/tmpxft_000013bf_00000000-14_hellomake.o: In function `main':
tmpxft_000013bf_00000000-3_hellomake.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x5): undefined reference to`myPrintHelloMake()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [hellomake] Error 1

---

What might be the problem?

Answer (score 3):

You could change the filename `hellofunc.c` to `hellofunc.cpp`.

If the filename cannot be changed, you could search more information about how to invoke C functions in C++ code.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the name of `hellofunc.c` to `hellofunc.cu`. You may also use `#include "hellofunc.h"`.